# Rounding to two decimal places in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rounding

Using Python 2.7 how do I round my numbers to two decimal places rather than the 10 or so it gives?

```
print "financial return of outcome 1 =","$"+str(out1)
```

Comment: This could be a can of worms. Are you storing financial data in a floating point variable and now want to round that? *Exact* rounding is not possible in most cases. You might want to use integers or `Decimal`s, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Learn about format specifiers. You can directly print float values, without converting them to strings.

Answer (score 203):

Use the built-in function [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> round(1.2345,2)
1.23
>>> round(1.5145,2)
1.51
>>> round(1.679,2)
1.68
```

Or built-in function [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format(1.2345, '.2f')
'1.23'
>>> format(1.679, '.2f')
'1.68'
```

Or new style string formatting:

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(1.2345)
'1.23
>>> "{:.2f}".format(1.679)
'1.68'
```

Or old style string formatting:

```
>>> "%.2f" % (1.679)
'1.68'
```

help on `round`:

```
>>> print round.__doc__
round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number

Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may be negative.
```

Comment: The string formatting method is useful when working with Decimals. 

E.g. `Decimal("{:.2f}".format(val))`

Comment: @PatchRickWalsh Or simply `Decimal(format(val, '.2f'))`.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about that format builtin.  After exploring more, I think this is the most accurate way of rounding if floating point errors are absolutely not acceptable: `Decimal('123.345').quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` gives you `Decimal('123.35')`.  On the other hand `Decimal(format(Decimal('123.345'), '.2f'))` gives you `Decimal('123.34')` because the binary representation of 123.345 is less than 123.345.

Answer (score 50):

Since you're talking about **financial** figures, you *DO NOT WANT* to use floating-point arithmetic. You're better off using Decimal.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("33.505")
Decimal('33.505')
```

Text output formatting with new-style `format()` (defaults to half-even rounding):

```
>>> print("financial return of outcome 1 = {:.2f}".format(Decimal("33.505")))
financial return of outcome 1 = 33.50
>>> print("financial return of outcome 1 = {:.2f}".format(Decimal("33.515")))
financial return of outcome 1 = 33.52
```

See the differences in rounding due to floating-point imprecision:

```
>>> round(33.505, 2)
33.51
>>> round(Decimal("33.505"), 2)  # This converts back to float (wrong)
33.51
>>> Decimal(33.505)  # Don't init Decimal from floating-point
Decimal('33.50500000000000255795384873636066913604736328125')
```

**Proper way to round financial values**:

```
>>> Decimal("33.505").quantize(Decimal("0.01"))  # Half-even rounding by default
Decimal('33.50')
```

It is also common to have other types of rounding in different transactions:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> Decimal("33.505").quantize(Decimal("0.01"), decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
Decimal('33.50')
>>> Decimal("33.505").quantize(Decimal("0.01"), decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('33.51')
```

Remember that if you're simulating return outcome, you possibly will have to round at each interest period, since you can't pay/receive cent fractions, nor receive interest over cent fractions. For simulations it's pretty common to just use floating-point due to inherent uncertainties, but if doing so, always remember that the error is there. As such, even fixed-interest investments might differ a bit in returns because of this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), too:

```
>>> print "financial return of outcome 1 = {:.2f}".format(1.23456)
financial return of outcome 1 = 1.23
```

Answer (score 4):

When working with pennies/integers. You will run into a problem with 115 (as in $1.15) and other numbers.

I had a function that would convert an Integer to a Float.

```
...
return float(115 * 0.01)
```

That worked most of the time but sometimes it would return something like `1.1500000000000001`.

So I changed my function to return like this...

```
...
return float(format(115 * 0.01, '.2f'))
```

and that will return `1.15`. Not `'1.15'` or `1.1500000000000001` (returns a float, not a string)

I'm mostly posting this so I can remember what I did in this scenario since this is the first result in google.

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, for financial data use decimal numbers, not floats.

Comment: I ended up converting most everything to integers. It seems to be much easier to work with. However, I wasn't doing anything that deals with fractions of pennies.

Answer (score 2):

The best, I think, is to use the [format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function:

```
>>> print("financial return of outcome 1 = $ " + format(str(out1), '.2f'))
// Should print: financial return of outcome 1 = $ 752.60
```

But I have to say: don't use round or format when working with financial values.

Comment: `format` requires non-string for f format. If not you got a ValueError. The correct code is: `format(out1, '.2f')` without casting to string

Answer (score 2):

When we use the round() function, it will not give correct values.

you can check it using,
round (2.735) and round(2.725)

please use

```
import math
num = input('Enter a number')
print(math.ceil(num*100)/100)
```

Comment: Please add an example you tested, the results and what do you think is wrong with them.

Comment: import math
num = input('Enter a number')
numr = float(round(num, 2))
print numr

Answer (score 1):

```
print "financial return of outcome 1 = $%.2f" % (out1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple workaround is to convert the float into string first, the select the substring of the first  four numbers, finally convert the substring back to float.
For example:

```
>>> out1 = 1.2345
>>> out1 = float(str(out1)[0:4])
>>> out1
```

May not be super efficient but simple and works :)

Comment: This method is very unreliable. If your value has more than one digit before the decimal point you don't get the two wanted decimal places. Same problem with a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding up to the next 0.05, I would do this way:

```
def roundup(x):
    return round(int(math.ceil(x / 0.05)) * 0.05,2)
```