# How can I stop printing a float 3 spaces after decimal?

Tags: python

I'm sorry, I know this must be a duplicate, I can't find where else it's posted. Please feel free to link me to the original question and mark this as duplicate.

I would like to print a 3 digits of a number AFTER  the decimal point in it. 
For example:

```
number = 523.637382
```

I would like to print: 523.637
I have a feeling I can use something similar to this

```
print(str(number)[:7])
>>>523.637
```

However, this will not work if the number before the decimal is not 3 decimals.

Bonus points: 
Would this be easy?

```
number = 500.220
#magic
>>>500.22

number = 500.2000003
#magic
>>>500.2
```

Comment: In Java you can format a string using placeholder like %.2f etc. to change how much decimals/width/etc should have the output variable... maybe in python exists something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (built-in) function that could do this is `round`:

```
>>> number = 523.637382
>>> rounded = round(number, 3) # 3 decimal places, for example
>>> rounded
523.637
```

This has already been answered for example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470883/how-to-round-to-two-decimal-places-in-python-2-7)

The good news, to answer the second part of your question, is that the `round` function automatically removes trailing zeroes. It's much harder to retain the zeros if you're defining a new variable: you need the `decimal` module; but it looks that that isn't necessary here.

```
>>> number = 523.60000001
>>> rounded = round(number, 3)
>>> rounded
523.6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print("%.3f" % number)
```

or, using the new-style formatting,

```
print("{0:.3f}".format(number))
```

Comment: Or even `format(number, ".3f")` since it's just one value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing a `str` like above you can use string interpolation:

```
number = 33.33333
print("{0:.3f}".format(number))
#=> 33.333
```