# Django decimal rounding

Tags: django

I have this function and I want to allow only 2 decimal places for the value.

This is not a model field but it's being calculated from them. What is the right way to do it?

```
@property
def value(self):
    value = self.average_flow_rate * (self.d_n / 1000) / self.nu
    if 2320 < value < 4000:
        return 4000
    else:
        return value
```

Comment: use built-in method `round(value, 2)`

Comment: If you want decimals (not floats), use the stdlib's  `decimal` module instead (and django DecimalFields for your model)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round to two decimal places in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470883/how-to-round-to-two-decimal-places-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 2):

This should work like a charm:

```
round(self.d_n, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. The problem was at template rendering where I had put: `{{ form.instance.value|stringformat:"d" }}` instead of ".2f"