# Trying to end up with two decimal points on a float, but keep getting 0.0

Tags: python-3.x

I have a float and would like to limit to just two decimals.

I've tried format(), and round(), and still just get 0, or 0.0

```py
x = 8.972990688205408e-05
print ("x: ", x)
print ("x using round():", round(x))
print ("x using format():"+"{:.2f}".format(x))

output:
x:  8.972990688205408e-05
x using round(): 0
x using format():0.00
```

I'm expecting 8.98, or 8.97 depending on what method used. What am I missing?

Comment: `8.972990688205408e-05` = `0.00008972990688205408`, why are you surprised that it gets rounded to 0?

Comment: because your `x = 0.00008972990688205408` which rounded to 2 decimal points is `0.00`

Comment: `format` seems to do what you want!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python (and many other programming language), any number suffix with an `e` with a number, it is power of 10 with the number.

For example

```
8.9729e05 = 8.9729 x 10^3 = 8972.9
8.9729e-05 = 8.9729 x 10^-3 = 0.000089729
8.9729e0 = 8.9729 x 10^0 = 8.9729
8.972990688205408e-05 8.972990688205408 x 10^-5 = 0.00008972990688205408
8.9729e  # invalid syntax
```

As pointed out by other answer, if you want to print out the exponential round up, you need to use the correct [Python string format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html), you have many choices to choose from. i.e.

```
e   Floating point exponential format (lowercase, precision default to 6 digit) 
e   Floating point exponential format (uppercase, precision default to 6 digit).
g   Same as "e" if exponent is greater than -4 or less than precision, "f" otherwise
G   Same as "E" if exponent is greater than -4 or less than precision, "F" otherwise
```

e.g.

```
x = 8.972990688205408e-05
print('{:e}'.format(x))   # 8.972991e-05
print('{:E}'.format(x))   # 8.972991E-05
print('{:.2e}'.format(x))   # 8.97e-05
```

(Update)

OP asked a way to remove the exponent "E" number. Since str.format() or "%" notation just output a string object, break the "e" notation out of the string will do the trick.

```
'{:.2e}'.format(x).split("e")  # ['8.97', '-05']
print('{:.2e}'.format(x).split('e')[0])  # 8.97
```

Comment: Ok, so using ```print('{:.2e}'.format(x)   # 8.97e-05``` how does one get rid of the ```e-05```? I just need 8.97.

Comment: @funk101 split() is python 101.   ;)

Comment: Yeah, I get it, I thought there would be a simple function that would do that, rather than split().

Comment: @funk101  Though Exponential handling is pretty standard across all programming language, I don't think stripping the  `e` number is a general practice.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the scientific notation. As glhr pointed out in the comments, you are trying to round `8.972990688205408e-05 = 0.00008972990688205408`. This means trying to round as type float will only print the first two `0`s after the decimal points, resulting in `0.00`. You will have to format via `0:.2e`:

```
x = 8.972990688205408e-05
print("{0:.2e}".format(x))
```

This prints:

```
8.97e-05
```

You asked in one of your comments on how to get only the 8.97.
This is the way to do it:

```
y = x*1e+05
print("{0:.2f}".format(y))
```

output:

```
8.97
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only want to round the mantissa/significand? If you want to keep `x` as a `float` and output a `float`, just specify the precision when calling `round`:

```
x = round(8.972990688205408e-05,7)
```

Output:

```
8.97e-05
```

However, I recommend converting `x` with the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) first, which "provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic" (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39726846/3115244)):

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal('8.972990688205408e-05').quantize(Decimal('1e-7')) # output: 0.0000897
print('%.2E' % x)
```

Output:

```
8.97E-05
```

Or use the short form of the `format` method, which gives the same output:

```
print(f"{x:.2E}")
```

Comment: The variable `x` is already a float number, no conversion required

Comment: It's not required, just recommended for arithmetic further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
rount() returns closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits,
```

so there is no chance you will get 8.98 or 8.97. you can check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) also.