# round down in python (multiple of 0.10)

Tags: python

I need to round down when the decimal is different from a multiple of 0.10
For example

```
36.09- 36.00 /
36.10- 36.10/
36.17- 36.10/
36.33- 36.30/
36.66- 36.60/
36.82- 36.80/
36.98- 36.90
```

cents should be only(
only accepted) 0.10 / 0.20 / 0.30 / 0.40 / 0.50 / 0.60/ 0.70 / 0.80 / 0.90

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to two decimal places in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470883/rounding-to-two-decimal-places-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It works by using the python `math` library to floor the value.

```py
# number is the amount of money (e.g. 36.66)
number = math.floor(number*10)/10
# number now becomes 36.60
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `round(x, 1)` because it will round up, so you have to implement it yourself

```
def round_down(x):
     return int(x * 10) / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon everyone.
Those of us in technology, the first thing we do is search on Google or research. generate ideas that can be specified in a solution.
I initially thought, to separate the integer from the decimal and validate the decimal with the valid values ​​for me. I do not think the observations on: "did you look for them on the internet or did you do something?" Thank you all for your solutions and comments.