# How can I round long decimal numbers into 0.00 format

Tags: python

My numbers like **3.8485341e-06, 9.9999619e-01, 2.9322797e-20**. How can I turn them into a number between 0-1. For example **0.89, 0.47, 0.14**

Comment: They're already between 0 and 1?

Comment: Are you trying to round them?

Comment: But I need them in X.xx format, Yes actually I need to round them

Comment: Two of the three examples you gave would come out to 0.00. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes thank you for help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding to two decimal places in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470883/rounding-to-two-decimal-places-in-python-2-7) - I don't know why it specifies 2.7. The same methods still work.

Comment: Yes I solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the exponential form with this:

```
a=3.8485341e-06
'{0:.20f}'.format(a)
```

or this

```
print("%.20f" % a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to format them into a string in the format you can use `f"{x:.02f}"`.

```
>>> x = 9.9999619e-01
>>> f"{x:.02f}"
'1.00'
```

Or for older versions of Python, `"{:.02f}".format(x)`.